# Boneh DDH Paper - Sampling Integers in Random Reduction

Tags: diffie-hellman, provable-security, hardness-assumptions

I've been reading [Dan Boneh's DDH paper](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/pubs/papers/DDH.pdf), in particular section 3.1 which covers DDH randomized reduction.

The first two sentences of theorem 3.1 state: Let $\Bbb G = \{G_p\}$ be a family of finite cyclic groups of prime order. Let $s(p)$ be an
efficiently computable function such that $|G_p| \leq s(p)$ for all $p$.

If I understand this correctly, for a given group in practice we can set $s(p) = p$ if we know the order of the group.

In section 3.1, he describes a statistical experiment in which you can construct a DDH triplet or a random triplet from an existing DDH or random triplet respectively by sampling integers $u_1, u_2, v$ from the range $[1, s(p)^2]$ and following the formula given.

I am struggling to understand the purpose of sampling in the range $[1, s(p)^2]$. Why not just sample from $[1, s(p)]$?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler game. There is an unknown modulus $m$, for which you know an upper bound $M \ge m$. You must devise a strategy for sampling an *integer* $x$ such that $y = x \bmod m$ is close to uniform in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Does it work to choose $x$ uniformly in $\mathbb{Z}_M$? No, consider the case of $M= 1.5m+1$.

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
x & 0 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & m-1 & m & m+1 & \cdots & M-1  \\
\hline
y = x \bmod m & 0 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & m-1 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & m/2 
\end{array}$$
In this diagram, each column is chosen with equal probability. The output value $y$ is highly non-uniform in $\mathbb{Z}_m$. In fact, you can easily distinguish $y$ from uniform by the simple distinguisher "is $y < m/2$?" The distinguisher says yes with probability 2/3 with this example, but only probability 1/2 for the uniform distribution (on $\mathbb{Z}_m$).

How does this work in the general case?
Each $y$ has either $\lceil M/m \rceil$ or $\lfloor M/m \rfloor$ values of $x$ that map to it. (In this example, each $y$ had either 1 or 2 values of $x$ that map to it.)
More precisely, exactly $r = (M \bmod m)$ of the $y$'s will have the higher number of associated $x$ values.
So the distinguisher "is $y \le r$?" will be the optimal distinguisher and you can easily compute its advantage as:
$$
  (M \bmod m) \left( \frac{\lceil M/m \rceil}{M} - \frac{1}{m} \right)
$$

We can upper-bound this advantage as follows:
$$
  \le
  (M \bmod m) \left( \frac{\lceil M/m \rceil}{M} - \frac{ \lfloor M/m \rfloor }{M}\right)
  \le
  \frac{M \bmod m}{M}
  <
  \frac{m}{M}
$$

Now, what if we used a bound $M$ such that $M > m^2$ (not just $M>m$) and we are sure that $m$ is exponentially large in the security parameter?
Then the statistical distance from uniform would be bounded by $m/M < 1/m$, which is negligible.

In other words, sampling from $\mathbb{Z}_M$, where $M > m^2$, results in a value whose residue mod $m$ is close to uniform.

---

**Connection to the DDH reduction algorithm:**
The reduction algorithm takes as input a triple of elements whose discrete logs are $(a,b,c)$.
It outputs a triple whose discrete logs are $(av+u_1, b+u_2, cv+bu_1+avu_2+u_1u_2)$.
We want to say the following:

- if $c \ne ab$ (i.e., the input is not a DH triple), then the output is statistically close to uniform over all triples --- i.e, the output discrete logs are close to uniform in $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^3$.
- if $c=ab$, then the output is statistically close to uniform over the set of DH triples --- i.e., the discrete logs of the first two outputs are uniform in $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^2$ and the discrete log of the third output is the product of the first two.

Arithmetic on these discrete logs happens naturally mod $p$, by the actions of the group. If you don't know $p$ then you must choose $v, u_1, u_2$ over the integers (e.g., in $\mathbb{Z}_M$ for some bound $M$) and argue that you still get a result that is close to uniform mod $p$.

You will soon find yourself in a situation like above, where if your choice of $M$ is bad then the result has high statistical distance from uniform.
That's why you will need to choose a bound $M$ that is larger than $p^2$.
Since $p$ is exponentially large in the security parameter, this gets you negligibly close to uniform in the result.

**Note:** it would also work to say $M > p 2^\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the security parameter.
Then you would conveniently bound the statistical distance by $1/2^\kappa$.
I agree that $M>p^2$ is a little sneaky because one factor of $p$ is plays the role of a bound on $p$, and the other factor of $p$ plays the role of a bound on $2^\kappa$.